# How can I re-run a nunit test programmatically in 3.2?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

In nunit 2.6.4, I used below C# code to re-run a failed test:

```
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty);
```

But after upgrading to nunit 3.2, TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest returns null. How can I re-run a test in 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this as follows....

```
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution;

TestActionCommand command = new TestActionCommand(CommandBuilder.MakeTestCommand(TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest as TestMethod));
command.Execute(TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext);
```

Comment: While that should work in the current build, it shares the drawback of the original solution, which is that it uses internal classes subject to change in the future. That said, it's fairly safe at least for a while. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to re-run your tests because they fail occasionally because of transient network errors or the like, NUnit 3.x introduced a [Retry](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Retry-Attribute) attribute that will retry a test a given number of times.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to programatically change the retry count in a setup method for eg?

Comment: No, the retry count is a fixed max. I would just try to determine a suitable number for your situation.

Comment: Is there a way I can re-run the test as I used to in nunit 2.6.4? The reason I want to do this is because I have the retry count as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of how this could be done in NUnit 3.x is wrapping the test code which can cause the failure in a loop and put a try catch block inside the loop that just continues in the catch block.

You can pass in a retry count parameter and just count it in the loop and then fail the test once you have reached the max number of retries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that what you were doing in NUnit 2.6.4 was not a supported way of running tests. It only worked by virtue of using a number of internal classes. I suggest using the published APIs and requesting features where you need them rather than using internal classes and methods that may change arbitrarily in the future.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do this using the APIs?

Comment: I used the TestEngine to run the test. This runs onetimesetup, setup, test, teardown and onetimeteardown methods. But is there a way to run setup, test, and teardown methods only?

Comment: No. The engine is capable of directing the framework to run tests but not of changing how tests are run. The basic building blocks of a test, such as OneTimeSetUp and SetUp are only understood by the framework.

Comment: @Charlie The link is a 404 now.  Are there instructions on running tests using NUnit 3+?

Comment: Best info currently is at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Engine-API-Spec